# How can I access the browsers localStorage in Blazor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I want to support JWTs, so I need to keep the token around; is there some facility to access this? Or should we just be registering our own javascript function to access this functionality for now?

Edit: per advice, I attempted to use JS interop as :

```
<script>
    localStorage.setItem("key1", "key1data");
    Blazor.registerFunction("readStorage", (key) => {
        return localStorage.getItem(key);
    });
</script>
@if (jwtKey == null)
{
<div class="login-panel">
    <p>JWT not loaded</p>
</div>
}
else
{
<div class="login-panel">
    <p>@jwtKey</p>
</div>
}

@functions {
    public RenderFragment Body { get; set; }
    string jwtKey;

    protected override async Task OnInitAsync()
    {
        jwtKey = RegisteredFunction.Invoke<string>("readStorage", "key1");
        if (jwtKey == null)
        {
            jwtKey = "Unknown";
        }
    }
}
```

But this results in a WASM error in diag:

> WASM:
>   [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Browser.Interop.JavaScriptException]
>   Could not find registered function with name 'readStorage'. WASM:
>   Error: Could not find registered function with name 'readStorage'.

FYI, this is in the MainLayout.cshtml of the Blazor VS boilerplate project.

(can make a new Question if appropriate; somewhat related to this one though)

Comment: I've tested this with a button as trigger, and works a expected. I'm guessing the script is executed after the async call. So you should register your function earlier in the process

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For 0.1 you need to write your own javascript interop. But I believe this is something worked on, and maybe in the 0.2 release.

Alternatively (if you don't need storage between sessions) you can write your own DI singleton, like done here: https://github.com/aspnet/samples/blob/master/samples/aspnetcore/blazor/FlightFinder/FlightFinder.Client/Services/AppState.cs

**Edit**
There is an open PR for this, so indeed should be there soon: https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/pull/205

**Edit2**
0.2 is done, but no localstorage yet. In the meantime i've developed a package for this: [BlazorExtensions](https://github.com/floreseken/BlazorExtensions) also on nuget

Comment: Awesome, thanks :) I tried to follow your advice to use the existing interop, but it seems not to be working? (updating question to illustrate)

Comment: Ah, yes, that fixed it. It seems that there should be a way to serialize operations for this type of situation (i.e., if the user is logged in, they get one panel vs another). In case the blazor team is running low on work items :)

Comment: What I do is register my javascript functions in the app.cshtml just below the router tag, you should try that.

Comment: Doesn't change the behavior on my system (still throws); that seems like perhaps it's a patch on the timing issue to make it more likely the javascript is executed first, but dangerous without assurance that it will. Really, the cleanest solution is obviously `while(true) { try { Invoke() } catch (JavaScriptException) { await Task.Delay(100); } }` (/sarcasm)

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft has its own package [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.ProtectedBrowserStorage`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.ProtectedBrowserStorage) But as of now **it is not production** ready yet and it is only for server side blazor.

If you don't want to have third-party dependency you can easily implement it via `JS interop`.

```
public class LocalStorage
{
    private readonly IJSRuntime _jsRuntime;

    public LocalStorage(IJSRuntime jsRuntime)
    {
        _jsRuntime = jsRuntime;
    }

    public async Task SetAsync(string key, object value)
    {
        string jsVal = null;
        if (value != null)
            jsVal = JsonSerializer.Serialize(value);
        await _jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("localStorage.setItem", 
            new object[] { key, jsVal });
    }
    public async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string key)
    {
        string val = await _jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("localStorage.getItem", key);
        if (val == null) return default;
        T result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(val);
        return result;
    }
    public async Task RemoveAsync(string key)
    {
        await _jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("localStorage.removeItem", key);
    }
    public async Task ClearAsync()
    {
        await _jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("localStorage.clear");
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
await _localStorage.SetAsync("Test", 42);
var val = await _localStorage.GetAsync<int>("Test");
await _localStorage.RemoveAsync("Test");
await _localStorage.ClearAsync();
```

Comment: This is a good solution, but could be made more robust.  System.Text.Json doesn't handle anonymous objects well.  Using NewtonSoft.JsonConvert with TypeNameHandling enabled gives much better results. Also, GetItem is really the only method that needs async/await or that requires a type parameter.  SetItem could just accept any object. +1

Comment: That ProtectedBroserStorage package is deprecated, apparently since may 2022

Answer (score 3):

It might be implemented by default into Blazor but for now I'm using:
[Nuget - BlazorStorage](https://github.com/cloudcrate/BlazorStorage)

Comment: Its not working with latest version - .net core 3 preview 5
https://github.com/BlazorExtensions/Storage/pull/27

Answer (score 3):

In case someone else is struggeling with this (as of juni-july 2018): 
Steve Sanderson addresses this very issue (localstorage) in his NDC conference video here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JU-6pAxqAa4
from around minute 45 or so.

He uses a a nuget package for this:
https://github.com/cloudcrate/BlazorStorage 
Usage examples on the page, so no need to repat here.

Answer (score 2):

There is now a package called **Blazor.Extensions.Storage** which is a curated extension
https://github.com/BlazorExtensions/Storage