# What causes if/else expressions to be re-evaluated?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

Working off the Blazor hosted template, in my MainLayout.cshtml, I have something like:

```
@inject UserInfo userInfo
@if(userInfo.Name == "bob")
{
    <div class="login-panel">
        <p>Hi Bob!</p>
    </div>
}
else
{
    <LoginPanel />
}
```

and then in a separate Login.cshtml:

```
@inject UserInfo userInfo
async void Login()
{
    userInfo.Name = "bob";
}
```

But logging in doesn't cause a change to the 'login-panel' in MainLayout.cshtml. I was able to get this to work if everything is in a single file and I am only checking for whether a particular variable is null or not (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49704857/how-can-i-access-the-browsers-localstorage-in-blazor/49704943?noredirect=1#comment86423613_49704943)), so I assume the Blazor framework has specific criteria which illicit a page to re-evaluate such blocks. Is this accurate? If so, what is the best way to force this re-evaluation?

Edit: I played around with it a bit more, eventually discovered the `StateHasChanged` protected member function, which I assume is called after Init has completed, hence why the previous example works. I think a working solution is to have my `UserInfo` object implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and then register a change handler inside MainLayout.cshtml to call `StateHasChanged()` for views that need to update when login status changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Blazor uses something called `StateHasChanged` just like `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

However the difference is, in **XAML** frameworks the **XAML** will **only** update those properties which has called `INotifyPropertyChanged`, but in Razor when `StateHasChanged` is called the UI framework will refresh the whole UI tree of the component (*at least as of now*) the element is residing. 
Then who has called the `StateHasChanged` if its not done by you. When an element gets an input (You are clicking a button) the blazor will automatically set the `StateHasChanged` under the hood.

More reads"

https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/issues/409

https://learn-blazor.com/pages/data-binding/

https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/issues/359

https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/issues/407